# csproj and n-tier application

Tags: csproj, .xproj

In my application have at least 3 layers/tiers; like Data, Business, Web.

As the project was created in xproj format, I'm seeing the "Data" references in the "Web" tier. 
This was not happening in csproj. How do I isolate better?